# jQuery ajax data post problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been searching to the answer for a while, I want to be able to parametrise my plugins AJAX values. So e.g. rather than:

```
$.post('test.aspx', { name: 'bob' }, function(data){
....
});
```

I want to parametrise name and the value used in the post so e.g.

```
var var1 = 'name';
var var2 = 'bob';
$.post('test.aspx', { var1: var2 }, function(data){
....
});
```

My problem is that it inserts the value 'bob' but posts it as 'var1' rather than 'name'. And on the server side it is expecting name not var1.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you know ajaxSetup? http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajaxSetup#options

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try building a hash for your data and then passing it to the `post` function. Like so:

```
var data = {};
data[var1] = var2;
data[var3] = var4;

$.post('test.aspx', data, function(returnData) { blah, blah blah; });
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var var1 = "bobsname";
    var var2 = "bob";

    ajax(var1, var2)

    function ajax(name, variable)
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            data: name + "=" + variable,
            url: "action.php",
            success: function(html)
            {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Im using the [ajax function](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options).